# Is there any way to debug why angular route is not being recognised?

Tags: angular

I have no idea why the router won't match any of the routes give... I have even tried really simple ones, yet the all fail.

My routes (extract):

```
{
    path: ':rootFolder/',
    children: [
        {
            path: 'name/**',
            component: MainComponent,
        },
        {
            path: 'name/*', //  Debugging only
            component: MainComponent,
        },
        {
            path: 'name',   //  Debugging only
            component: MainComponent,
        },
        {
            path: '',
            component: MainComponent,
            pathMatch: 'full',
        },
    ],
},
{
    path: ':rootFolder/:currentFolder/',
    children: [
        {
            path: 'name/**',
            component: MainComponent,
        },
        {
            path: '',
            component: MainComponent,
            pathMatch: 'full',
        },
    ],
},
```

Also, I am certain, these routes are being accepted by the router as if I use `UrlMatcher`, I will get the correct behaviour. I just want to use the standard build-in solution rather than this...

Solving this problem is one thing, but I would love to learn why and possibly help others...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enable routing debugging in this way:

Declare the settings object

```js
    const settings: ExtraOptions = {
        enableTracing: true,
    };
```

and then use it when you declare your router:

```js
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, settings)],
```

Doing so, you'll have the output in the browser console.

Note: you can also condense the `settings` object inline.

Comment: That's true but it will only show events. I usually use that to debug why scrolling hasn’t started, or what guards it went thought.

Answer (score 2):

Okay. So first up, there's an issue with the configuration itself.

The issue is with the parent paths. They can't be suffixed with a `/`. If you remove that from both the parent routes, then everything would work as expected.

So change `path: ':rootFolder/',` to path: ':rootFolder',

And change `path: ':rootFolder/:currentFolder/',` to `path: ':rootFolder/:currentFolder',`

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: ':rootFolder',
  children: [
    {
      path: 'name/**',
      component: MainComponent,
    },
    {
      path: 'name/*', //  Debugging only
      component: MainComponent,
    },
    {
      path: 'name',   //  Debugging only
      component: MainComponent,
    },
    {
      path: '',
      component: MainComponent,
      pathMatch: 'full',
    },
  ],
},
{
  path: ':rootFolder/:currentFolder',
  children: [
    {
      path: 'name/**',
      component: MainComponent,
    },
    {
      path: '',
      component: MainComponent,
      pathMatch: 'full',
    },
  ],
}]
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-config-unique?file=src/app/app.module.ts) for your ref.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "/"

```
path: ':rootFolder',
```